# Upload failed: PDF links (URLs) are not allowed. See EDAS FAQ

Tags: hyperref, ieeetran, urls

I tried to upload my paper which is written by Latex to the IEEE conference organized in "https://edas.info/", but gives me this error.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
 
\hypersetup{%
   unicode   =false,    % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
   pdftoolbar=false,    % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
   pdfmenubar=true      % show Acrobat’s menu?
}




\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please complete your example to a full but minimal example that others can copy and test for them selfs. Additionally you might want to cite the error you get.

Comment: It is not fully clear what the problem is, but either hyperlinks are not allowed at all by the publisher (in which case you should remove `\usepackage{hyperref}`, `\hypersetup` and all explicit uses of hyperref functionality in your document), or only web links are not allowed (in which case you should remove any uses of `\url` or `\href` and possibly move urls in the bibliography to a `note` field and make them verbatim).